# easiest way to change text to UPPERCASE/lowercase in windows 7

Tags: text-editing, capslock, typing

I want to change a size of letters from upper to lower case in every field where text could be typed (internet browsers or notepad, or explorer).
But i don't know how it could be done instead of retyping all word from the beginning with pressed caps lock button.
I typing everyday and constantly facing this problem.

The way I want to do it is done in notepad++ - selecting the text, pressing right mouse button and select change case of letters.

I'm using a windows 7 operating system.
Maybe there is a built in function in windows OS that help me to change text form lower to upper case?
Maybe there is a programs to help me to do that?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved.
I just found programs on the internet that help to solve my problem.
It is very disappointing that windows os doesn't have built in functionality like that.
From now I use programs that change capitalization like LangOver, Key Switcher, EveryLang, Keyboard Ninja.
In particular I chose Keyboard Ninja for the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to find a solution on a per application basis.  There is no way to do this globally in Windows.

For example the following plugin for Chrome will do what you are asking

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/convert-case/dnhnjnbopnnlbjemjepcpcfchmfpafoj?hl=en

You will have to just Google around for "[ApplicationName] Change Case Plugin" and see what comes up

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is with a simple Powershell Script.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Window.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^x"); # cut
[System.Window.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait([System.Window.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText().ToLower()); # rewrite as lowercase
```

You can use this by creating the script and assigning it a shortcut. (You'll also need to make sure it starts without starting up any window). I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

You'll then be able to highlight your text and execute the script with your key shortcut.